# error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 31

Tags: python, jupyter, analysis

This is the code I am trying to run
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import emojy
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from wordcloud import wordcloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator
# Extract the Date Time

```
def date_time(s):
    pattern='^([0-9]+)(\/)([0-9]+)(\/)[0-9]+),([0-9]+), ([0-9]+)[]?(AM|PM|am|pm)?-'
    result= re.match(pattern,s)
    if result:
        return True
    return False


#extract contact
def find_contact(s):
    s=s.split(':')
    if length(s)==2:
        return True
    else:
        return False


#Extract message
def getmessage(line):
    slpitline=line.split('-')
    datetime=splitline[0];
    date,time=datetime.split(',')
    message=''.join(splitline[1:])

    if find_contact(message):
        splitmessage=message.split(':')
        author=splitmessage[0]
        message=''.join(splitline[1:])
    else:
        author=None
        return date,time,author,message
data=[]
filepath=r"C:\Users\91808\Downloads\Buddingchat.txt"
with open (filepath,encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    fp.readline()
    messageBuffer=[]
    date,time,author=None, None, None
    while True:
        line=fp.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        line=line.strip()
        if date_time(line):
            if len(messageBuffer)>0:
                data.append([date,time,author,''.join(messageBuffer)])
            messageBuffer.clear()
            date,time,author,getmessage(line)
            messageBuffer.append(message)
        else:
            messageBuffer.append(line)
```

Are there any error in the definition of the date_time and the parenthesis of the date_time?

This is the error I got while running this code :
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 3>()
10     break
11 line=line.strip()
---> 12 if date_time(line):
13     if len(messageBuffer)>0:
14         data.append([date,time,author,''.join(messageBuffer)])

```
Input In [7], in date_time(s)
      3 def date_time(s):
      4     pattern='^([0-9]+)(\/)([0-9]+)(\/)[0-9]+),([0-9]+), ([0-9]+)?(AM|PM|am|pm)?-'
----> 5     result= re.match(pattern,s)
      6     if result:
      7         return True

File ~\anaconda3\lib\re.py:191, in match(pattern, string, flags)
    188 def match(pattern, string, flags=0):
    189     """Try to apply the pattern at the start of the string, returning
    190     a Match object, or None if no match was found."""
--> 191     return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\re.py:304, in _compile(pattern, flags)
    302 if not sre_compile.isstring(pattern):
    303     raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
--> 304 p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
    305 if not (flags & DEBUG):
    306     if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:
    307         # Drop the oldest item

File ~\anaconda3\lib\sre_compile.py:764, in compile(p, flags)
    762 if isstring(p):
    763     pattern = p
--> 764     p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
    765 else:
    766     pattern = None

File ~\anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py:964, in parse(str, flags, state)
    962 if source.next is not None:
    963     assert source.next == ")"
--> 964     raise source.error("unbalanced parenthesis")
    966 if flags & SRE_FLAG_DEBUG:
    967     p.dump()

error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 31
```

Please give any idea  regarding the solution of this questuion

​

Comment: Your regex has an unmatched paren, specifically here `[0-9]+)` is missing the opening paren

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your pattern, an unbalanced parenthesis at char 31 means:

```py
pattern='^([0-9]+)(\/)([0-9]+)(\/)[0-9]+),([0-9]+), ([0-9]+)[]?(AM|PM|am|pm)?-'
#                                       ^ this is unbalanced
```

You can fix it by balancing it, also I'd recommend using raw-strings for regexes which removes the need for most escaping.

Since we lack context and input/output for this regex, this is the best I can guess:

```py
pattern=r'^([0-9]+)(/)([0-9]+)(/)([0-9]+),([0-9]+), ([0-9]+)[]?(AM|PM|am|pm)?-'
```